# esper aggregation count query output unexpected

Tags: streaming, complex-event-processing, esper

I am sending city-name, company-name to esper.

These queries will count occurrences of name company pair in 5 seconds:

```
create context FiveSecondsContext start @now end after 5 seconds; 

context FiveSecondsContext 
        insert into AggregatedEvent1 
                        select count(*) as count, company, name from eBay group by name, company output snapshot when terminated;
```

below query should give a max-count for each city at the end of FiveSecondsContext. It seems right with my knowledge in SQL, but it doesnt give me max, it returns all the rows in AggregatedEvent1.

```
   insert into AggrEvent2 
                select max(count) as value, company, name from AggregatedEvent1 group by name;
```

Since above is going wrong, my query below

```
select count(*) as cnt, company from AggrEvent2 group by company;
```

which tries to count the city names where a company (say: "yahoo") has a max count also goes wrong and gives me count of all the occurrences of the company name in the initial query input.

1. Either issue is with groupby clause , or
2. I need to figure the order in which the queries will run. Since I only have the context defined for AggregatedEvent1.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what is in the select and what is in the group, same as in a relational db. You can read up on that in here: http://esper.codehaus.org/esper-5.0.0/doc/reference/en-US/html_single/index.html#processingmodel_aggregation_output
Removing "company" from the select or adding company to group would seem to do it.

Comment: Not sure if issue is with aggregation or context